# Can a subshell fetch an argument within the parent shell scope?

Tags: shell, arguments

I want to run different versions of a utility onto the same data like so:

```
current_dir$ (cd my_utility_version_dir && exec ./my_util my_data_file)
```

Is there a way for my_util to look for my_data_file in current_dir?

Answer (score 3):

If you run

```
(cd my_utility_version_dir && exec ./my_util "$OLDPWD/my_data_file")
```

then

1. `my_util`'s current working directory (`.`) will be `my_utility_version_dir`
2. It will have been given the path to `my_data_file` in the *previous* working directory - the one you `cd`ed out of.

Whether that looks for it there or not depends on exactly how `my_util` works inside, but it would be pretty common that it accepted a path to use.

Comment: Works like a charm! (rep<15)